# python: why does os.makedirs cause WindowsError?

Tags: python, windows

In python, I have made a function to make a directory if does not already exist.

```
def make_directory_if_not_exists(path):
    try:
        os.makedirs(path)
        break    
    except OSError as exception:
        if exception.errno != errno.EEXIST:
            raise
```

On Windows, sometimes I will get the following exception:

`WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\...\\my_path'`

It seems to happen when the directory is open in the Windows File Browser, but I can't reliably reproduce it. So instead I just made the following workaround.

```
def make_directory_if_not_exists(path):
    while not os.path.isdir(path):
        try:
            os.makedirs(path)
            break    
        except OSError as exception:
            if exception.errno != errno.EEXIST:
                raise
        except WindowsError:
            print "got WindowsError"
            pass
```

What's going on here, i.e. when does Windows `mkdir` give such an access error? Is there a better solution?

Comment: From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.makedirs) : `Raises an error exception if the leaf directory already exists or cannot be created.`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, I know. I already catch this exception with `except OSError`. I'm asking about `WindowsError`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little googling reveals that this error is raised in various different contexts, but most of them have to do with permissions errors. The script may need to be run as administrator, or there may be another program open using one of the directories that you are trying to use.

Answer (score 6):

You should use OSError as well as IOError.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22027508) answer, you'll use something like:

```
  def make_directory_if_not_exists(path):
    try:
        os.makedirs(path)
    except (IOError, OSError) as exception:
        if exception.errno != errno.EEXIST:
           ...
```

Answer (score 0):

on your question on a better solution i would use simple and clear three lines code here:

```
def make_directory_if_not_exists(path):
    if not os.path.isdir(path):
        os.makedirs(path)
```