# Python: Getting a WindowsError instead of an IOError

Tags: python, windows, exception

I am trying to understand exceptions with Python 2.7.6, on Windows 8.

Here's the code I am testing, which aims to create a new directory at `My_New_Dir`. If the directory already exists, I want to delete the entire directory and its contents, and then create a fresh directory.

```
import os

dir = 'My_New_Dir'
try:
    os.mkdir(dir)
except IOError as e:
    print 'exception thrown'
    shutil.rmtree(dir)
    os.mkdir(dir)
```

The thing is, the exception is never thrown. The code works fine if the directory does not already exist, but if the directory does exist, then I get the error:

> WindowsError: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'My_New_Dir'

But according to the Python documentation for os.mkdir(),

> If the directory already exists, OSError is raised.

So why is the Windows error being thrown, rather than the Python exception?

Comment: kind of relevant: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3151/ (clunkyness addressed in Python 3)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`WindowsError` is a subclass of `OSError`. From the [exceptions documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.WindowsError):

> Raised when a Windows-specific error occurs or when the error number does not correspond to an `errno` value. The `winerror` and `strerror` values are created from the return values of the `GetLastError()` and `FormatMessage()` functions from the Windows Platform API. The `errno` value maps the `winerror` value to corresponding `errno.h` values. This is a subclass of `OSError`.

You are trying to catch `IOError` however, which is *not* such a parent class of `WindowsError`; as a result it won't suffice to catch either `OSError` nor `WindowsError`.

Alter your code to use the correct exception here:

```
try:
    os.mkdir(dir)
except OSError as e:
```

or use `WindowsError`; this would tie your code to the Windows platform.

Comment: Ah, I'm an idiot, I just used the wrong exception. Thanks for pointing it out for me, it works fine now!

Answer (score 3):

You mis-read it. It is "OSError" not "IOError", and WindowsError is a subclasss of "OSError" for your specific working OS.

```
>>> issubclass(WindowsError, OSError)
True
```

Besides, for your propose, this API is better:

> os.path.isdir(path): Return True if path is an existing directory. This follows symbolic links, so both islink() and isdir() can be true for the same path.

```
if os.path.isdir(dir):
    shutil.rmtree(dir)
os.mkdir(dir)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you search for "WindowsError" on the [exceptions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html) page, you will see that `WindowsError` is in fact a Python exception.  It is a subclass of `OSError`, so the documentation is still correct.  If you change to

```
try:
    os.mkdir(dir)
except OSError as e:
    print 'exception thrown'
    shutil.rmtree(dir)
    os.mkdir(dir)
```

then you will catch the exception.