# Message <class WindowError> in reading recursavely a directory

Tags: python-3.x, exception, io

I started to study Python 3 and, for fun, I'm trying to code a small software that, from a directory root, read recursively the filesystem and stores some informations about files in a csv file, but I'm receiving this exception

```
<class 'WindowsError'>
```

that I don't understand well. It looks like a problem of **import**, but I use this code

```
def buildsinglefile(currentfile, directory):
    x = SingleFile(currentfile, directory)
    return x

def walkdir(root_path):
    # traverse root directory, and list directories as dirs and files as files
    readfiles = []
    print(root_path)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_path):
        path = root.split(os.sep)
        for file in files:
            print('file>'+file)
            row = buildsinglefile(file, path ).tocsv()//here exception
            readfiles.add(row)
        for directory in dirs:
            walkdir(directory)
```

All that I'm doing is (in *Java developer* state of mind :) ) in the **main** file (not inside a class):

1. parsing filesystem with **os.walk**
2. call the function **buildsinglefile** that creates an Object
3. put this object in a list

The point 2 is uncorrect, but I don't understand why.
Do you think everything?

Thank you

Comment: You may want to inspect the `SingleFile` object/class that you're using on line `x = SingleFile(currentfile, directory)`. What is `SingleFile`? Is that a class you created? If I comment out those lines, your code works for me (I don't get any errors) but no `csv` file gets created yet. Also, you might want to compare your code to this similar code with same Error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22027508/python-getting-a-windowserror-instead-of-an-ioerror

Comment: Hi, I understood my error: **SingleFile** is a mine class, but I tried to manage the file in variable _file_ as an instance of java class File (with every method available) and this grows an exception

Comment: Hi. What method is `.tocsv()`? is it in `SingleFile` class? It's not in `buildsinglefile`. If that line you //commented is causing the exception we should know where the method `.tocsv()` is and how does it work?